# Elixir/Phoenix - implement authentication without a database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I intend to use Elixir and Phoenix LiveView to develop a front-end only application. My elixir app will be consuming an external REST API. This API has a `/login` endpoint that returns the current user information and a bearer token that can be used to access the other endpoints.

My initial attempt was the `phx.gen.auth` solution, but it uses database tables. What strategy would be apt for my use case?

Comment: just replace context database calls with calls to external api, there is no ready solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Run `phoenix.new --no-ecto test_project`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.